# matching range of dates in two different excel tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am struggling days now to find a way to match two different tables in excel with the range of dates.

**MY EFFORT** on matching is :

```
=IF(AND($A2=$F2;$B2=$G2;$C2=$H2;$D2=$I2);ABS($E2-$J2)/$E2;"NO MATCHING")
```

but I know the date condition is not right.
Any help?

Comment: Hello, What do you mean by "but I know the date condition is not right"? On a quick glance to the attached picture everything seems fine.

Comment: @dmb to check if  the date in the second data frame  is in the range of a month from the date in the first data frame (for example he/she declares a weight (100 kg) in 2020/1/1 and appears it in 2020/1/15 but the actual weight is 105).

Comment: Let me recap, you sent a sample picture that appears to work just fine but you still think the date criteria is wrong, then when inquired you talk about some unit(kg) that is not in the sample further more using other time format. Also I can't help to notice that there is not an actual question.

Comment: it works but it doesn't result the desired output

Comment: I suggest you  **edit** your question to post **AS TEXT** (*which can be copy/pasted into a worksheet*), an example of the two data tables that demonstrates your problem, and also the actual and expected results ***from that data***.  One way to post as text is to use this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and then format the result as "Code".  The results can be posted as a screenshot.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am sharing the file in g sheet link : [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Yh8qaU2aVZYlr3wJ2prT7knn6q3WSVE0Y4CcD_u9ww/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Problem 1:  Your dates are not all real dates.  If the table came from a CSV file, you probably OPEN'd the file instead of IMPORTing the file.  Some dates got interpreted incorrectly; others were left as text.  You will need to fix that first.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i have import it and to me appear just fine as the original excel file.Sorry for that.But ok it’s my first and only  post.Don’t bother to leave it.Thanks for effort and your editing suggestions anyway

Comment: @NikosTsiantakis Change the format of the date column from "custom" to "General".  If they are true dates, they should all convert to five digit numbers looking like `44708` or similar.  If they are NOT real dates, some will convert and some will not.  Tell me what happens.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have changed it.If someone can see it and help I will appreciate it.

Comment: OK 2nd problem:  You have multiple instances of `ID, SPECIES, GEAR` in each table.  How do you decide which to match?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The id,species gear must be the same obviously.Now the date is the problem.Because someone might declare that has 1500 kg of FRZ with PS in 4/9/2020 and appear 1505  of FRZ with PS in 5/9/2020.How can I search and match this one day latency (in this example).Normally they appear it the same day or in some cases they will delay one week or 15 days.

Comment: For Example, take `FRZ and `PS`.  There are nine instances with nine different dates.  So if you have `FRZ`, `PS` and `12-MAY-2020` in `Table1`, which of the 9 matches in `Table2` do you use to compare the date with?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the closest date of table1 of course .Think that the kilos of table2 in date2 must be very close to kilos of table in date1.I don't know if I help you.It;s a complicated problem.Imagine: I am a fisherman that I have trawl 1500 kg of a specific type of fish (Species) with a specific fishing gear (PS) on day 4/9/2020. I declare them and I keep them on my boat.The next day i finally arrive at port and weight the fish and are not 1500 as I have declared but their actual weight is 1505.Matching the Id the gear and the species is easy.This time latency is my problem

Comment: You will need a VBA or Power Query solution, preferably Power Query unless you **MUST** use Excel 2007.  And I assume you want the landing date to be the closest date **on or after** the table 1 date

Comment: Thanks for effort and help.I really do

Comment: Is this formula correct? =IF(AND($A2=$F2,ABS(G2-B2)<=7,$C2=$H2,$D2=$I2),ABS($E2-$J2)/$E2,"NO MATCHING")

Comment: @Lee Landing date not in same row as log date. Also can have multiple landings on same day that match for date but not for amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, this can be done in Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ (and Office 365).

But some things left out of your description for which I made assumptions

- Landing date cannot be before Logbook date (how can you land fish that you haven't caught)
- You sometimes have multiple landings on the same day for the same ID, Species and Gear.

  - I chose to match only the landing that was closest to the logged amount
  - Sometimes this resulted in large differences between the landing and logbook
  - Not sure what this is due to (consolidation of landing from other days, maybe)?

    - If that is the case, probably you need to inspect manually.
- PQ takes a long time to run on your data (about 20 sec on my machine).  This is probably due to the multiple table filtering operations.  Might be able to speed it up if otherwise OK.

For PQ in Excel 2010, you will need to download and install the [Microsoft Power Query Add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379&CorrelationId=a46d78d6-c834-4afc-9b19-3f960ac82328).

To use Power Query

- Make both of your data tables into **Tables**

  - This will either be on the `Insert` tab; or on the `Home` tab (format as table).
- Select some cell in your Table1 (or whatever you've named the first table)
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` (*might be different with the Add-in)
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in table 1 and set data types
//Be sure to change `Name`  of table to the actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//Buffering this table seems to reduce speed of execution from 60 sec to about 20 sec
    Table1 = Table.Buffer(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"ID", type text}, 
        {"DATE", type date}, 
        {"SPECIES", type text}, 
        {"GEAR", type text}, 
        {"LOGBOOK", Int64.Type}})),

//Read in table 2 and set data types
//Be sure to change `Name`  of table to the actual table name in your workbook
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    Table2 = Table.Buffer(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{
        {"ID", type text}, 
        {"DATE", type date}, 
        {"SPECIES", type text}, 
        {"GEAR", type text}, 
        {"LANDING", Int64.Type}})),

//Join the two tables based on ID, SPECIES and GEAR
    Joined = Table.NestedJoin(Table1, {"ID", "SPECIES", "GEAR"}, Table2, {"ID","SPECIES","GEAR"},"Joined"),

//filter Joined subtable by minimum landing date that is >= logged date
// **I assumed that landing date MUST be AFTER log date.**
//If that is not the case, then code change will be needed
    filteredTbl = Table.AddColumn(Joined, "Filtered Table", each
         let 
            dt = [DATE],
            minDT = List.Min(List.Select([Joined][DATE],each _ >= dt))
        in 
            Table.SelectRows([Joined], each [DATE] = minDT)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(filteredTbl,{"Joined"}),
   
    //landing date will be any row in filtered table unless table is empty
    landingDT = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "LANDING DATE", 
        each if Table.IsEmpty([Filtered Table]) then null 
        else [Filtered Table][DATE]{0}, Date.Type),

    //landings will be the value with the least difference from that logged on the landingDt
    landings = Table.AddColumn(landingDT, "LANDING", each
     if [LANDING DATE]=null then null 
     else   let 
                lb = [LOGBOOK],
                ld = List.Transform([Filtered Table][LANDING], each Number.Abs(_ - lb)),
                posMinDiff = List.PositionOf(ld,List.Min(ld))
            in 
                [Filtered Table][LANDING]{posMinDiff},Int64.Type),

    //Match if landing date LTE log date + 7 days
    match = Table.AddColumn(landings, "MATCH", each Duration.TotalDays([LANDING DATE]-[DATE])<=7,Logical.Type),

    //calculte difference between landings and logged, if there is a Match
    //sometimes the differences are quite large.
    //maybe an error, or consolidation of multiple logged valaues?
    //not sure what do with large differences
    landingsDiff = Table.AddColumn(match, "Landing Diff", each if [MATCH] = true then [LANDING] - [LOGBOOK] else null, Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(landingsDiff,{"Filtered Table"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

**Initial Data Tables** *(Partial)*
[image]

As an example of what I am writing about with regard to large mismatches in landing/logbook amounts, it appears that your LOGBOOK entries for 17-Jun and 23-Jun `ID **31/SBS/PS` may have been combined into a single landing on 24-Jun

**Results** *(Partial)*
[image]

Post back with any comments/questions.